# Alter table variable to add primary key get error Incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, primary-key

I want add a composite primary key constraint to a defined table variable depending on a condition:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Col1 int, Col2 int)

IF [myCondition] 
    ALTER TABLE  @tbl ADD CONSTRAINT c PRIMARY KEY(Col1)
ELSE 
    ALTER TABLE  @tbl ADD CONSTRAINT c PRIMARY KEY(Col1,Col2)
```

But get:

> Incorrect syntax near '@tbl'.

Comment: You can't do ddl statement conditionally like that, not to mention that your alter statement is a different name than the table variable declared. If you want to do this it would have to be with dynamic sql.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` is not allowed on table variables

Comment: You could accomplish this with an old fashion #temp table ....

Answer (score 0):

Alter statements can't be used on table variables.

As an alternative, use a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (Col1 int not null, Col2 int not null)

IF [myCondition] 
    ALTER TABLE  #tbl ADD CONSTRAINT c PRIMARY KEY(Col1)
ELSE 
    ALTER TABLE  #tbl ADD CONSTRAINT c PRIMARY KEY(Col1,Col2)
```

Comment: Edited, the columns have to be defined as "not null" to add them as a PK.